# Enable datagridview by click on button - MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have little problem. I got datagridview with some data. Inside datagrid are checkboxes. For my APP i using MVVM pattern. Now what i want to do. I have button, which must enable datagrid. In xaml, i have datagrid disabled by some multitrigger conditions based on checked checkboxes. But i want to allow user to enable datagrid, by click on button. Im not sure how to do it in MVVM pattern. By using code behind i will violate the MVVM pattern.

For example this i have in my xaml code:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                        <Style.Triggers>                                               
                                                <!--Je-li truck ve stavu nakládá, pak povol naložit, pokud naložený již není. Pokud je naložen, řádek je nepřístupný.-->
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.EntityNotifiedTruck.ConvertEnumToStr, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDeliveryDetail}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="Nakládá" />
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsLoaded,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True" />                                                            
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />

                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.EntityNotifiedTruck.ConvertEnumToStr, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCDeliveryDetail}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="Nakládá" />
                                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsLoaded,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False" />
                                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
```

And this

```
  <Button Content="ODBLOKOVAT VÝKLADKU" Command="{Binding UnLoadTruckCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="865,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource DialogButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="22">
 </Button>
```

Is my button with command, which i want to allow user enable datagrid again, if is disabled. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't you bind IsEnabled property of Datagrid?

Comment: I can but how it will solve this? :) I need complex conditions when datagrid can be enabled or not.

Comment: You are using MVVM so your VM must have all the property values. If you can check for all the conditions in VM then it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ItemsControl then instead of passing the datagrid as the command parameter to the button command, name the ItemsControl and pass the same as follows:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestCollection}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Name="dgDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="2,0,2,2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

.....

In the view model use the following to access the data grid:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl _itemsControl = parameter as System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl;
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid = _itemsControl.FindName("dgDatagrid") as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code behind has never been a violation of MVVM, nor will it ever will be. The violation you are talking about is using\affecting the ViewModel from the code behind. You can use the code behind to affect the View (xaml) and it does not violate the pattern - code behind is for View stuff only.

So in your OP you can use code behind and have no need to go to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to access your grid in the view model, though it might break the MVVM convention slightly but all the code remains in the view model.

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="Test" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgDatagrid}"/>
```

"dgDatagrid" is the name of my data grid in xaml which is being passed as the command parameter.
This is my command in view model:

```
testCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteTest);
private void ExecuteTest(object parameter)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid = parameter as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
        grid.IsEnabled = true/false;
    }
```

You will have to add and use the control's namespace reference in your view model but this is the only way if you want to avoid code in the code behind file.

Comment: That might work. But i have another little problem. I have all datagrids in ItemsControl - so in code behind i see name only from this ItemsControl, but i dont see names of grids. Any tips how to solve this?

Comment: Im trying to use it, but there is another problem. In obj it return null state. Because i have User Control in which is datagrid and main window where i have the button.  So this is little bit complicated for binding. But i will solve this.

Comment: You just have to find your resource through the visual tree, I was just showing the approach.